# Cordova PushPlugin doesn't fire onNotificationAPN after restart

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications

I have an app setup (Phonegap) that uses PushPlugin for notifications, it all works fine apart from when you restart the app. The onNotificationAPN works when the app is installed and then run, it also works fine when the app is in the background (i.e. all notifications work).

The problem happens when I restart the app, if I restart the app the 'onNotificationAPN' no longer seems to get called, although notifications are still received and the console outputs "notification received", and if you run the app in the background you get the notification banner. Without 'onNotificationAPN' being called I cannot display the notification in the foreground when the user has the app open.

Right now I am using the standard example function provided from the PushPlugin source:

```
function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    if (e.alert) {
         $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
         // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
          navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }

    if (e.sound) {
         // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
         var snd = new Media(e.sound);
         snd.play();
    }

    if (e.badge) {
         pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
    }
}
```

As I have mentioned above, the notifications work fine until you restart the app.

Any clues?

Thanks.